# Swift - Custom Segue Error (Ambiguous use of 'view')

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to make a custom segue and it keeps telling me that I am using an **ambiguous use of 'view'**. Can anyone explain what's going on?

> Code:

```
import UIKit

class customSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        let sourceVC: AnyObject = self.sourceViewController
        let destinationVC: AnyObject = self.destinationViewController

        sourceVC.view.addSubview(destinationVC.view)

        destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in

            destinationVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)

            }) { (finished) -> Void in

                destinationVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

                let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.001 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

                dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                    sourceVC.presentViewController(destinationVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

> The 3 Lines of code that give error - Ambiguous use of 'view' :

sourceVC.**view**.addSubview(destinationVC.view)

destinationVC.**view**.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.05, 0.05)

destinationVC.**view**.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you are getting these errors is that you are typing your `sourceVC` and `destinationVC` variables as `AnyObject`. You must type your variables as a `UIViewController` so swift can see the correct `view` attribute. Your variable declaration would then look like this:

```
let sourceVC: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController
let destinationVC: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController
```

Comment: It worked and now I understand why it gave me an error. Thanks a lot for the help!